Tap-to-click not working at all in Kubuntu 22.04
Tap-to-click has stopped working. I don't know when it stopped working. I'm using Kubuntu 22.04.
The touchpad works fine for normal cursor navigation and scrolling.  The touchpad buttons do work, but they are clunky and loud compared to the tap-to-click option.
Boxes are checked in KDE's GUI settings that should enable the feature:

xinput list yields:
Virtual core pointer                id=2    [master pointer (3)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer           id=4    [slave pointer (2)]
↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad           id=12   [slave pointer (2)]
The output from xinput --watch-props 12 indicates that tapping is NOT enabled, despite what the GUI settings show.
Is there some other enabling that needs to be done?
Here is the output from xinput --watch-props 12:
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':  
Device Enabled (177):   1  
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (179): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000  
libinput **Tapping Enabled (313): 0**  
libinput Tapping Enabled Default (314): 0  
libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (315):    1  
libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (316):    1  
libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (317):       0  
libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (318):       0  
libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (319):  1, 0  
libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (320):  1, 0  
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (321):       0  
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (322):       0  
libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (323):    1  
libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (324):    1  
libinput Scroll Methods Available (325): 1, 1, 0  
libinput Scroll Method Enabled (326):   1, 0, 0  
libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (327):   1, 0, 0  
libinput Accel Speed (328):     0.000000  
libinput Accel Speed Default (329):     0.000000  
libinput Accel Profiles Available (330): 1, 1  
libinput Accel Profile Enabled (331):   1, 0  
libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (332):   1, 0  
libinput Left Handed Enabled (333):     0  
libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (334):     0  
libinput Send Events Modes Available (298):     1, 1  
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (299): 0, 0  
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (300): 0, 0  
Device Node (301):      "/dev/input/event5"  
Device Product ID (302): 2, 7  
libinput Drag Lock Buttons (335):       <no items>  
libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (336):       1  
libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance (337): 15  
libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance Default (338): 15  
libinput High Resolution Wheel Scroll Enabled (339):  


Only 33 views and 0 comments or answers after 4 days.  I am interpreting this as a strong message to get my shit together and upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04.  You guys are absolutely right.  Thank you for the clear communication.

I changed over to my installation of Kubuntu 24.04.  Now I can tap-to-click all I want.  Yay!
